# WP Canvas - Gallery doesnt show gallery and outputs error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, gallery

I am using WP Canvas - Gallery module and I have following problem:

- my gallery is not visible
- console show me error that $container.masonry is not a function.
  PRNTSCREEN -----> http://prntscr.com/7hwjfs

LINK TO THE PLUGIN -------> https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-gallery/